# Spambots are cluttering my log file [Django]

Tags: python, django, apache, spam-prevention

I have a nice and lovely Django site up and running, but have noticed that my `error.log` file was getting huge, over 150 MB after a couple of months of being live. Turns out a bunch of spambots are looking for well known URL vulnerabilities (or something) and hitting a bunch of sub-directories like `http://mysite.com/ie` or `http://mysite.com/~admin.php` etc.

Since Django uses URL rewriting, it is looking for templates to fit these requests, which raises a `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception, and then a 500 message (Django does this, not me). I have debug turned off, so they only get the generic 500 message, but it's filling up my logs very quickly.

Is there a way to turn this behavior off? Or perhaps just block the IP's doing this?

Comment: The 500 is a Django thing, I'll edit the post to make that clearer.

Comment: It's 500.  It's not *necessarily* a bad request; as developers, we happen to know that the client's just probing.  Django, however, assumes that the developer forgot to include a URL.

Comment: this is really a question for sysadmins, not programmers

Comment: @hop - I guess you could see it that way, but I am looking for a programmatic solution for the 500 errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um, perhaps, use [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) to rotate and compress the logs periodically, if it isn't being done already.

Comment: It is not being run. That might be the best way, though I'd rather do something about the 500 errors.

Comment: I would definitely get logrotate up and running. That aside, the part about 500 confuses me. If there is no view attached to a URL, it should always give a 404, debug or not, no?

Comment: @ayaz - Yeah, a 404 makes sense to me, I'm guessing it's a Django thing.

Answer (score 4):

If you can find a pattern in UserAgent string, you may use `DISALLOWED_USER_AGENT` setting. Mine is:

```
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS = (
    re.compile(r'Java'),
    re.compile(r'gigamega'),
    re.compile(r'litefinder'),
)
```

See the description in [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#disallowed-user-agents).

Comment: But this won't avoid the log lines, just change what status code is returned.

Answer (score 3):

"Is there a way to turn this behavior off?" - the 500 is absolutely mandatory.  The log entry is also mandatory.

"Or perhaps just block the IP's doing this?" - don't we wish.

Everyone has this problem.  Just about everyone uses Apache [log rotation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#rotation).  Everyone else either uses an OS rotation or rolls their own.

Answer (score 3):

Django should be throwing a 404, not a 500, if the URL doesn't match any entries in your URLConf.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#handler404

You need to provide a 404 template:

> If you don't define your own 404 view -- and simply use the default, which is recommended -- you still have one obligation: To create a 404.html template in the root of your template directory. The default 404 view will use that template for all 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up a catch-all pattern as the last item in your urls file and directing it to a generic "no such page" or even your homepage? In other words, turn 500's into requests for your homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Why not fix those "bugs"? If a url pattern is not matched, then a proper error message should be shown. By adding those templates you will [help the user](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000819.html) and yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it should be a 404, not a 500. 500 indicates something is trying to deal with the URL and is failing in the process. You need to find and fix that.
2. We have a similar problem. Since we are running Apache/mod_python, I chose to deal with it in .htaccess with mod_rewrite rules. I periodically look at the logs and add a few patterns to my "go to hell" list. These all rewrite to deliver a 1x1 pixel gif file. There is no tsunami of 404s to clutter up my log analysis and it puts minimal load on Django and Apache.

You can't make these a**holes go away, so all you can do is minimize their impact on your system and get on with your life.

Answer (score -1):

A programming solution would be to :

- open the log file
- read the lines in a buffer
- replace the lines that match the errors the bots caused
- seek to the beginning of the file
- write the new buffer
- truncate the file to current pointer position
- close

Voila ! It's done !